# Phantomjs has status 'fail' of loading css

Tags: html, phantomjs, status

I'm using 1.9.1 version of PhantomJS. And also tried to use 1.9.0 version of PhantomJS and a fresh build of latest master. Phantom does not load css and has status 'fail'. I also tried to use local and other servers like apache.
For testing I use this code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

var cssUrl = 'http://31.31.201.139:8001/download/any.css';
var otherUrl = 'http://31.31.201.139:8001/download/any.other';

page.open(cssUrl, function (status) {
    console.log('css status', status)
    page.open(otherUrl, function (status) {
        console.log('other status', status)
        phantom.exit();
    });
});
```

I've launched this on different operation systems and result was the same.

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `page.open` opens an HTML page, not a CSS file.

Comment: I had been trying to do that after I found that some page load results are failed. 
Then I enabled debugging by showing requests/response headers.
Actually when I load the page, phantomjs loads all its dependencies like js and css files.
I supposed that the problem in css file loading.

The page I tried to load is https://sports.bwin.com/en/sports/events/4/1899/3261172/betting/zenit-st-petersburg-fc-nordsj%C3%A6lland

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. The CSS assets for my page just don't load. I can download JS assets just fine. Help?

Comment: I am also facing same issue on an CSS. Any updates ?